# Blender Python Object Transform operations - return values / Thread lock?

Tags: python, scripting, objects

I recently stumbled upon the following problem of the data/context object API layer.
If one changes object values which are accessed by the scripting with

```
D.objects["MyObject"].location[0] = -3
```

This works mighty fine. The object moves to -3. If one has a big, heavy object, the transformation is - understandably - delayed. However, if I want to perform another operation which is dependent on the new location, i don't get any access to a return value.

I tried with the bpy.ops.transform API layer but that does only work when the cursor is in the right window. I tried overriding the Execution Context, as in https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6105/107059

The bpy.ops' return value {'FINISHED'} is something that comes in very handy. I need a functionality similar to this with the objects.location attributes (NOT calling any bpy.ops stuff...)

Is there any way to check if a direct transformation is finished or is this impossible?
I tried something along the lines of:

```
old_loc = D.objects["MyObject"].location[0]
D.objects["MyObject"].location[0] = -3
while old_loc == D.objects["MyObject"].location[0]:
    pass
do_another_transform()
```

But that will result in an endless loop. Also updating the view before performing the new transformation did not do anything. I basically need a thread-lock for the function.

Thanks for any hint or help in advance